# Quando, e perché, 'scopare' ha assunto il significato di 'avere un rapporto sessuale'?

Tags: idioms, history

Secondo il Treccani 'scopare', fra l'altro, significa:

> Avere un rapporto sessuale con qualcuno: non vuole s. con il primo che capita (spesso con la particella pron. si: l’ha portata a casa sua e se l’è scopata); con uso assol., avere un rapporto sessuale: lei non conosce i ragazzi di oggi … pensano solo a ballare e s. e prendere droga (Dacia Maraini).

Sapreste dire quando verbo 'scopare' assunse questo significato, e perché?

Comment: Non che ci volesse il Treccani per attestare questo utilizzo... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alle sue origini anche il verbo fregare aveva un significato di diretto riferimento 
all'atto sessuale (da e.g., *fricazione di corpi*). Scopare potrebbe aver assunto un significato analogo nello stesso momento, questo perché l'azione caratteristica dello spazzare in terra, richiede movimenti alternati per lo più mediante un oggetto il cui manico è trivialmente riconducibile a una forma fallica (rif., diz. etim. Zingarelli).

Per quanto riguarda il periodo invece non ho idea, ma sicuramente postumo al latino nel quale il verbo *scopare* ha origine tarda.

Aggiungo che ho trovato in rete che l'atto di pulire mediante ramazza era un'operazione appannaggio di mogli operose e soddisfacenti, :) considerazione che potrebbe perorare l'imporsi del nuovo significato del verbo.

Riferimenti e letture utili:

- http://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/scopare
- http://betapensiero.blogspot.hk/2011/12/trombare-fottere-o-fare-lamore.html

Comment: Vorrei rinforzare la idea che si tratti di un tardo latinismo, perché lo stesso concetto è presente in altre lingue latine.
In spagnolo "echar un polvo" (spolverare).

Comment: In realtà il "polvo" dell'espressione spagnola è di origine tuttora dubbia, essendoci varie ipotesi al rispetto. Fra le due più probabili troviamo: una che sostiene che provenga dall'abitudine di inalare tabacco in polvere nei secoli XIII e XIX per la quale aristocratici e borghesi si appartavano (un po' come l'"incipriarsi il naso" italiano); l'altra che sostiene che provenga dalla locuzione latina "memento homo, quia pulvis es et in pulverem reverteris", cioè "ricordati uomo, che polvere sei e polvere ritornerai". Il verbo "spolverare", invece, si traduce in spagnolo con l'espressione "quita